# Call a PHP function with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have a PHP page that has has the following in it:

```
<?php

class CallsClass {

    var $conn1;
    var $dataTable = "";

    function calls() {    
        $this->conn1 = new Datasource("taylor", "dbproj", "root", "elves") or die("Could not connect");

        $s1 = "SELECT id, UPPER(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname,' ',1)) as fullname, oldcode FROM `researcher` WHERE `display` = '1' AND fullname <> 'Jenny Porteous' AND fullname <> 'Carey-Lee Lendrum' AND fullname <> 'Carys Gibson'";
        $result = $this->conn1->_execute($s1);

        while ($row = $this->conn1->_nextAssocRow($result)) {
            $fullName = $row['fullname'];
            $dataTable .= $fullName;
        }
        echo json_encode($dataTable);
    }

}

?>

I know want to call this with my Ajax function:

$(document).ready(function() {
                    $(function () 
                    {
                        $.ajax({                                      
                            url: 'Queries/CallsQuery.php/calls',            
                            dataType: 'json',              
                            success: function(result)         
                            {
                                //console.log(result);
                            } 
                        });

                    });
```

I get an error of "OPTIONS file:///C:/Users/wesley/Desktop/Highcharts%20example/Queries/CallsQuery.php/calls() Resource failed to load" in the Google Chrome Dev Tools, any reason why?

Thanks,
Wesley

Answer (score 2):

The short version: Because you aren't using a web server.

---

Browsers do not support PHP. In the context of the WWW it is a server side programming language.

You need a web server to:

- Interpet a URI which passes data beyond the end of the filename
- Execute the PHP

---

Additionally, I'm not aware of PHP having the capability to treat having `/function_name` on the end of a URI as "Run this function inside the only class in the file".

It *might* have that feature, I'm not a PHP expert, but it seems a little bit too "Do what I might possibly mean" even for PHP.

The usual approach for this would be to have a controller handler that would check the URI and then execute the appropriate function.

Comment: got my vote for your latest edit. was half way through writing that out in an answer :)

Comment: Note for OP: you can't call php scripts with relative urls if you're not loading your web pages through a web server. You very well might have a web server, but if you're loading your html from `c:\\Users\...\myhtml.html` the relative path will point to `c:\\Users\...\myphp.php` which bypasses the web server (which will be listening on 127.0.0.1:8888 presumably)

Comment: @Quentin: _a little bit too "Do what I might possibly mean"_ cracked me up! +1 for that... and No, it doesn't support that kind of requests, unless you use a framework (which means a lot of other stuff has to happen first)

Answer (score 2):

*Edit:* Didn't even read the error, but Quentin is right: looks like *php* isn't doing anything: get xampp, read the docs and set up a quick server on your local machine, I'm recommending xampp because it's just dead-simple to set up, but doing it from scratch is more informative, as always

How would you expect this to work? A class is inert code, unless it's been instantiated. You're calling a *Member* function, which is in the script you send your request to. This script defines a class and, as far as it's concerned does a cracking job, and goes home for a refreshing beer.

You need an ajax script, that processes your request, creates an instance and *then* calls the appropriate member functions

---

Off topic, but still: on your jQuery code: why are you nesting the `ready` callback?

```
$(function ()
```

is short for

```
$(document).ready(function ()
```

So this doesn't make sense to me:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $(function ()
    {});
});
```

Comment: Looks like the error is a web server one, but the next problem he was going to encounter was the class methods one. :p

Comment: Most likely... this code is a bit like saying _"I've got the blueprint of a house, but when it rains, I'm still getting wet"_